# CNN vs DNN for image recognition

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Does CNN perform better than DNN in general in recognizing objects in images? Or is it the opposite?

For example, let's say one wants to detect hand-written digits encoded in 28x28 pixels images. In this case, which of the two architectures is preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1):

DNNs and CNNs aren't exclusive terms. A network can be deep, convolutional, both or neither. State-of-the-art results in computer vision are deep networks (having many layers) and are also convolutional neural networks (using convolutional filters).